# Linking repo subfolders with git

Tags: git, synchronization, bitbucket, data-synchronization, openshift

I have a project on Red Hat OpenShift (git) and a project on Bitbucket (git).

**How do I link a subfolder of the Bitbucket project to a subfolder of the OpenShift project?**

(so that making commits in one subfolder makes those same commits in the other)

Answer (score 1):

Git has a feature called [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) that allows you to do this; the cost is some added complexity when updating the project.  OpenShift should handle the submodules correctly, but I haven't personally tried it.  If you want to see how OpenShift handles submodules for git repos, please take a look at [this script](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-abstract/abstract/info/bin/deploy_git_dir.sh).

Answer (score 0):

Add both repositories as remotes to your local clone, and propagate commits with git fetch/push. If the servers can push to each other, and you have the ability to run hooks on them, you could set up an update-hook on one of the servers so that it automatically pushes to the other. See githooks(5)

Comment: And I can do this on subfolders; i.e.: without having to push an identical copy to different repo locations?

Comment: No, you need to use submodules to link folders within a single repo to another repo.